# Was the JWST's shipment from California to French Guiana kept secret or otherwise anonymized during transport?

Tags: launch, equipment, transport, logistics, ground-crew

It's not often that a sea ship is spotted with cargo worth [<s>one hundred</s>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTmXHvGZiSY) **ten billion dollars**.

I vaguely recall reading an article several months ago where someone from NASA mentioned that they would not be publicizing the route that would take the payload from California to its launch site in French Guiana, nor would they announce specific dates ahead of time, the idea being that with such a price tag and investment in time and energy, it was a prime target for ransom.

The new NASA press release [NASA’s... Space Telescope Arrives in French Guiana After Sea Voyage](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-s-webb-space-telescope-arrives-in-french-guiana-after-sea-voyage) contains the block-quoted information below, which is being announced *after the fact.*

**Question:** Was the JWST's shipment from California to French Guiana kept secret or otherwise anonymized during transport?

---

> NASA’s (JWST) successfully arrived in French Guiana Tuesday, after a 16-day journey at sea. The 5,800-mile voyage took (it) from California through the Panama Canal to Port de Pariacabo on the Kourou River in French Guiana, on the northeastern coast of South America.

> Late in the evening of Friday, Sept. 24, (it) traveled with a police escort 26 miles through the streets of Los Angeles, from Northrop Grumman's facility in Redondo Beach to Naval Weapons Station Seal Beach. There, it was loaded onto the MN Colibri, a French-flagged cargo ship that has previously transported satellites and spaceflight hardware to Kourou. The MN Colibri departed Seal Beach Sunday, Sept. 26 and entered the Panama Canal Tuesday, Oct. 5 on its way to Kourou.
>
> The ocean journey represented the final leg of (the space telescope's) long, earthbound travels over the years. The telescope was assembled at NASA's Goddard Space Flight Center in Greenbelt, Maryland, starting in 2013. In 2017, it was shipped to NASA's Johnson Space Center in Houston for cryogenic testing at the historic “Chamber A” test facility, famous for its use during the Apollo missions. In 2018, (it) shipped to Space Park in California, where for three years it underwent rigorous testing to ensure its readiness for operations in the environment of space.

> After (the telescope) is removed from its shipping container, engineers will run final checks on the observatory’s condition. (It) will then be configured for flight, which includes loading the spacecraft with propellants, before (it) is mounted on top of the rocket and enclosed in the fairing for launch.

[image: The MN Colibri arrived Oct. 12 at Port de Pariacabo on the Kourou River in French Guiana, carrying NASA’s James Webb Space Telescope as cargo. Credits: NASA/Chris Gunn]

> The MN Colibri arrived Oct. 12 at Port de Pariacabo on the Kourou River in French Guiana, carrying NASA’s James Webb Space Telescope as cargo. Credits: NASA/Chris Gunn

Comment: A quick search on https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels/MN-COLIBRI-IMO-9207390-MMSI-228057000 shows the port calls - Seal Beach and the Panama Canal. Doesn't seem to show French Guiana, but might if I subscribed and looked at the last day of history (more than 1 day cost$). Of course, even knowing all that would mean nothing without knowing, in advance, that JWST was on that ship.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact yes, the "hiding in plain sight" technique. If you'd like to dangle a limb in more dangerous waters I have a [ship-based question in Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/65960/16047)

Comment: One might suspect there were a few French Foreign Legion folks, just by accident of course, on the ship. Likely SOP for transporting satellites as it seems to do with some regularity.